# How to spawn multiple nodejs processes in OpenShift

Tags: linux, node.js, openshift, openshift-cartridge

In an OpenShift enviroment how could I run two NodeJS processes (from the nodejs official cartridge), each with its own startup file?

Basicaly I want to make a web application that will sometimes put jobs in a queue. I thought that I should have two proceses: one to handle the web requests and one to handle the jobs processing.

The reason is that I think processing the jobs in a separate process is that I think it could block the front end part if there are many jobs.

**These are my solutions so far** (but I dont really know if they are good)

- spawn the second process from an action hook (start and restart). I am worried that if the worker process dies it won't be automaticaly restarted
- from the main process call `fork` or `spawn`, etc. Same worries as the above
- do not use two processes at all, use only one

**Other details**:

- a job is mainly IO: a few HTTP requests to Google API (5-10 requests per job), also 2 simple requests to mongodb
- at first there wont be many jobs in the queue but its possibly to have many in the future
- I am planning to use [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) for the concurent feature and UI feature
- all of these things will be kept on a single server (scaling may occur but its highly unlikely)

Comment: Have you considered using a cron job to start the process? That way if it dies you could restart it.

Comment: @corey112358 I have considered running the whole worker from a cron. Now that you mention the cron could just keep the worker running. But I think there must be a better solution.